# React Native production build not working (Android)

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native

I have a application where I am using this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@logisticinfotech/react-native-music-picker) to get all music files from the storage and it's working fine in debug version but when I build it for the production mode the plugin is not working anymore. I have create a issue to the plugin repository but they still didn't didn't give any feedback . So I decide to ask to the developer community if anyone able to find the way to fix this problem. I am attaching [android log](http://bengalistories.in/log.html) for better understanding.

Gradle -

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 17
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        supportLibVersion = "29.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1')

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Package.json

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.2",
"@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^4.13.0",
```

Added this to AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="app.packagename.in">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
        android:name="app.packagename.in.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    >

    <!-- Add this SplashActivity -->
    <activity
            android:name="app.packagename.in.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
            android:name="app.packagename.in.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="packagename.in" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="packagename.in" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
            <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-**********"/>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="app.packagename.in.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

Let me know if anything or needed.